# How to override angular material theme from global css file

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material.
Sometimes I want to override built in themes which is in my case indigo-pink.css.
I do it like that:

```
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox:not(.mat-checkbox-disabled).mat-accent .mat-checkbox-ripple .mat-ripple-element,
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background, 
::ng-deep .mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
    background-color: #10014B !important;
}
```

and it is working fine for me. 
However, when I am using a same code from the global css file, where I set an encapsulation=none

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

the code in other files doesn't see my overriding css class.
Does anyone have any idea why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It should work if you remove `::ng-deep`. See the checkbox in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-theme-native-telnvg). Please note that I did not even have to set the `!important` flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write CSS at global level you don't have to use `::ng-deep` if their [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is higher they will be applied by default. To explore encapsulation more you can follow [Scoping Your Styles in Angular With ViewEncapsulation](https://alligator.io/angular/viewencapsulation/).